# Append Json data before sending to UI

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api2

I am getting an API Request and Processing for a Select Query Operation , same request I have to Append few more fields back to UI as response  .

I mean , Output of Select Query + Few other Properties needs to add on the JSON

Any thoughts ? I Use Angular2 and WebAPI

Comment: you need to add data in json at fronted or backend??

Comment: @ashsish sharma , looking for data in backend first